# Java ME tips for Java EE developer

Tags: mobile, java-me

I am used to programming in Java EE but right now I am being assigned to Java ME project. From what I am reading all those ME restrictions are quite painful. Do you have any tips on how to deal with such a crude language? Are there are any good libraries which might give a higher level of abstraction?

I am also looking for tips about developing tools or strategies e.g. tools like maven (I mean tools without which you can't imagine working). Are there are tools/approaches which you must know about in Java ME?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things to discuss here, you could write a book or two about the topic!

First of all, realize that "Java ME" is an umbrella term that encompasses a variety of Java environments, some very limited compared to Java SE, some nearly as capable. However, when most people use the term they're really referring to the limited side of things -- the CLDC (Connected Limited Device Configuration) and the MIDP (Mobile Information Device Profile). So let's assume that's where you're going.

The biggest problem you're going to face as a J2EE developer is the sheer LACK of APIs in a MIDP environment. Also missing language features -- no enums, no generics. Basically you're dealing with a subset of Java 1.3, which is a huge step back for you. The collections classes aren't there, for example, so you end up using the old-style Vector and Hashtable classes a lot. Or you end up using device-specific API extensions at the cost of portability.

The good news is that the NetBeans tools is pretty good for MIDP development, they've put in a lot of good features. You can also use Eclipse, there are some good plugins for that. The tool support is there, including ant tasks and so on.

There's lot of material on the web to get started with Java ME. Read some of my [Java ME overview](http://www.ericgiguere.com/j2me/overviews.html) material (which still refers to Java ME as J2ME). Then figure out what platforms you're targeting. If you're doing BlackBerry stuff, for example, you'll want to learn and use the BlackBerry APIs and not MIDP.

There's definitely a learning curve, but you'll adapt quickly enough.